# How to send a flutter app to client for testing

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have developed a flutter application and I want my clients to test it, how do I send both(android and iOS) applications for testing to them. I do not want them to get the source code, I just want the app to run on their mobile device so that they can test it.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: run `flutter build` command then

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do the following in the command line:

```
$ cd <project-folder>
$ flutter build apk
$ flutter build ios
```

References:

- https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android
- https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Answer (score 2):

While you can certainly build an APK or iOS package and distribute them, getting them on people's phones is not as easy as a normal client might want. If your client is non-technical, they may prefer the way they normally get apps on their devices.

Both Google Playstore and Apple Appstore have programs to distribute apps to testers before the final release. You can set up [testing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) in the [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish). With Apple, it's called [Testflight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).

This way, you can give your client the actual feeling of an app almost done, not just a hacky file they need to somehow get onto their phone with your help.

It is also a good test run to see if you have set up the store connection correctly.